# Can Django template {% load %} take a variable

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible for the django template {% load %} tag to take a variable. I'm trying to pass the name of the tag set from my view to the template html and using it like this: {% load {{filter}} %} where filter is the name of the variable with the tag set name string. However, doing so is giving me the error: {{' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

I want to load some tag sets dynamically since this template file is part of a reusable app and the tag set will depend on which application is using this app. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read the documentation for Custom Template Tags?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: I have, but the problem I'm facing is that I don't know the name of the tag set. I get that name through a view call and the view should pass the name to the template to load. So if the view sends back a variable filter_name which is actually the string "getattribute", I want to do something like {% load {{filter_name}} %} which evaluates to {% load getattribute %}

Comment: So you can do it through upload your_tag_library  and then using the custom tag to which you can provide different parameters and filters based on the use case, instead of trying to guess the tag. {% upload %} is for tag libraries, which may have more than a single tag, so if you want to branch the cases use {% if your_var_from_view %}{{ tag|filter }} {% endif %}

Answer (score 0):

In your template

```
 {% if condition_from_view_1 %}
       {% upload tag_library1 %}
 {% elif condition_from_view_2 %}
       {% upload tag_library2 %}
 {% endif %}
```

Similarly, you can take the check down to the tag level.